# How to output <br> through ajax response?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

ajax.php

```
 foreach ($errors as $e)    

 echo "<br>".$e;  // doesn't work

 echo $e."<br>";  // doesn't work

 echo "\n\n".$e;  // doesn't work

 echo $e."\n\n";  // doesn't work
```

My javascript :

```
 ...
 $.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  url: form.attr( 'action' ),
  data: form.serialize(),
  success: function( response ) {
    $("b#signupErr").html(response);
    $("b#signupErr").fadeIn();
  }
} );
 ...
```

Everything work as expected except that the < br > doesn't jump to new line

My html looks like the first image but I want something like the second image (see text in red):

```
   ![preview][1]
```

Comment: Did you debug your JS to find out the value of `response` inside your success handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `dataType: 'html'` to your `$.ajax` function declaration. It says to jQuery to parse the returned data in HTML.